# Website showing PHP source

Tags: php, sunos

I have a server running on SunOS 5.1, and I'm having an issue with the source of a php file displaying.  The source starts displaying after **=>** when setting up an array.  After the first **=>** it displays the rest of the file.  Why would this be happening?

Example source:
index.php

```
<?php

$tmpVar = 'just testing';
$tmpArray = array(
    'test1' => 'rawr1',
    'test2' => 'rawr2',
    'test3' => 'rawr3'
);

echo "Testing<br/>";    

?>
```

This would output:

```
'rawr1', 'test2' => 'rawr2', 'test3' => 'rawr3'); echo "Testing<br/>"; ?>
```

Comment: Do you have any code you could show us?

Comment: It's just a standard page, it displays perfectly fine on my Redhat server.  I wrote a small test page just to see, I'll give you the source of that.

Comment: maybe short tags are allowed on SunOS which is closing the PHP tag

Comment: Updated the question with a little sample source.

Comment: This is a server configuration problem, it's not a problem with the PHP code, you should detail your server info in a question on ServerFault.com.

Comment: Maybe something in apache/php config?

Comment: @Dan thanks, going to go post there instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The whole source is displaying, it's just interpreting the part before the `>` as an HTML tag so you don't see it. View source from your browser and you'll see that your file wasn't parsed at all. That's the problem, you haven't correctly configured your web server to parse PHP at all.

Comment: It parses everything else fine, until it hits an array using =>.  The rest of the page is displaying perfectly.

Comment: @Atrox What happens if you view the page source in your web browser? If Dan is right, you'll just see your entire php file, which isn't being interpreted as PHP at all, but as HTML.

Comment: @Atrox that means you are missing a tag its interpreting the > part of => as the end of a html tag. check your opening and closing tags

Comment: I've checked them all.  On a page with no array definitions it works fine.  This code is a mirror of a directory on another server, where it works flawlessly.